# Model clipped after OBJ import

Tags: import, obj

[image]

I imported an obj file and this is what I get. I cannot figure out how to solve this.

Comment: I scaled the entire model by .01 now it is visible

Comment: the problem was scaling

Answer (score 1):

Try lowering the clip start and increasing the clip end in the view panel?

[image]